# CUDA transfer memory during kernel execution

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia, pci

I know that CUDA kernels can be "overlapped" by putting them into separate streams, but I'm wondering if would it be possible to transfer memory during kernel executions. CUDA kernels are asynchronous afterall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run kernels, transfers from host to device and transfers from device to host concurrently.

http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/StreamsAndConcurrencyWebinar.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarification, the above are valid only if your device supports it. You can check it running device query and checking the attribute concurrent copy and execution

Comment: Thank you for the information, I knew it but it's always useful to repeat it